# Using a single voltage reference IC for several ICs?

Tags: adc, dac, voltage-reference

I have a circuit that has both a DAC and ADC that require a 2.5V reference. I could not find information regarding the operation of both devices from the single output of the Vref IC. Can this hurt the performance of either the ADC or DAC?

Comment: If your ref IC is capable of sourcing a few miliamps then there won't be any problems.

Comment: @RohatKılıç AD780ARZ does 10mA so I think it's fine. Thanks!

Comment: @RohatKılıç; this may or may not be the case, particularly if the DAC and ADC are charge redistribution devices. @User34920: can you identify the specific parts you are using?

Comment: @PeterSmith DAC is AD5732RBREZ, ADC is AD7718BRZ

Comment: The DAC is ok (REF is buffered) but the ADC reference input needs some consideration - see the 'Reference Input' discussion on page 39 of the datasheet.

Comment: @PeterSmith The Vref IC I'm using is AD780 which is one of the Vref sources listed on page 39. It seems both the ADC & DAC has input R of 5M for Vref input.